# Qt Deployement C++ set linked file to executable directory

Tags: javascript, html, qt

I'am working on a touchscreen app with Qt on win32, and i need to set the url of my linked file to the executable directory. (Like if i could do "./file")

```
QDir::currentpath doesnt seems to work, it load me nothing, ive tried : 
    _bridge->_view->load(QUrl(QDir::currentPath() + "/login.html"));
    _bridge->_view->load(QUrl(QDir::currentPath() + "login.html"));
    //or even 
    _bridge->_view->load(QUrl("./")); (i was hopeless)
```

Anyone got a trick or something to help me? TY

Answer (score 0):

Truly sorry being a douche.

```
_bridge->_view->load(QUrl("file:///" + QDir::currentPath() + "/login.html"));
```

//for Qurl link

```
std::string      url = ("file:///" + QDir::currentPath().toStdString() + "/Memory/Memory.txt");
```

//for url link.

My problem was in fact the "/release/" that Qt put in the end of the compilation directory.